# Remove blank gap between parallax boxes

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have a problem on my website [weeral.it](http://www.weeral.it/)

There are a blank gap between the two parallax section and between parallax section and the footer.

Is there a way to resolve this problem?
Many thanks!

Comment: You mean [these?](https://image.ibb.co/mVSA3Q/Capture.png)

Comment: Yes, I mean that blank gap.

Comment: You can use `.block.block-parallax_block {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}` to deal with the space in between the two sections but the visual effect is not great because the background images don't blend well. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want this effect. I try and it works, but there is a last blank gap in the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some find and replace work need into your main.css

find

```
body .normal-page, body .portfolio, body .blog {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

replace

```
body .normal-page, body .portfolio, body .blog {
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

need to remove this  `padding-bottom: 30px;` 
Then into your HTML remove the

tag  http://prntscr.com/fp31er

and it will look like something like this

[image]

Comment: Not work, I try to delete the "p" but the blank gap on the footer remains.

Comment: after remove p tag did you check again it is showing there again or not ?

Comment: I can't find the p tag because it is not a simple html file but a wordpress template.

Comment: I have double check you did not remove yet padding-bottom: 30px; from your main.css , first remove this and I am thinking about p tag OK

Comment: to remove p tag use this css .span12 > p {
  display: none;
} into your main.css

Comment: I remove padding bottom. Now? What can I do?

Comment: good now   .span12 > p { display: none; }       add this css into your main.css file

Answer (score 0):

The blank space just above the footer is being shown as a part of the `<div class="main-wrapper">` in the developer tools of the browser. Try including this

```
margin: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
```

to the wrapper `<div>` and the last `<div>` in the wrapper `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

There is extra padding at bottom and extra P tag after template-wrapper-22 ID tag.

[image]

main.css line number 120

```
body .normal-page, body .portfolio, body .blog {
    z-index: 100000;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* padding-bottom: 30px; */ 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not work, I try to delete the "p" but the blank gap on the footer remains.